# <div id="root"></div> not transfering in webpack build

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm using Webpack 3.8.1 and webpack-dev-server 2.9.2. This is for a project I am writing in react. Below is my webpack.config file.  Every time that I run the build command the   is not transferred to the index.html file in the dist directory.  This also happens when I do the production build as well. I can write the line into the index.html file but every time it is rebuilt it removes the line.  Any ideas?

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    hot: true
  },
  entry: {
    app: './src/index.js',
    vendor: ['react']
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin('dist'),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Production'
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: 'styles.css'
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin({
      multiStep: true
    })
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].[hash].js',
    sourceMapFilename: 'bundle.js.map'
    },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          'babel-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use:'css-loader'
        })
      },
      { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
      },
      { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader'
      },
      { test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader:'file-loader?name=img/[name].[ext]&context=./app/images'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ico)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader:'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]&context=./app/images'
      }
    ]
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
  }
};
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's happening because of html-webpack-plugin. You haven't specified hence you don't see it. After a quick glance at html-webpack-plugin [doc](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#writing-your-own-templates), I'd suggest you to create a `template.html` file with the content you want in your built index.html file.

And change the plugins section of your config to,

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
   title: 'Production'
   template: 'template.html'
}),
```

That way you can fill-in all the DOM you want in your template file and your built `index.html` will have that.

And to read configuration variables (title) in your `template.html` just use

`<title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>`

Comment: Thank you. I put `html-webpack-plugin` in separate `development` and `production` webpack files. But I just specify favicon on `production` config while the template I set on `common` file. And it seems to override the `common` configuration.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to create a template file, you might consider instead using the plugin, [html-webpack-root-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-root-plugin), which will insert a `<div id="root"></div>` in the generated HTML.

```
npm install html-webpack-root-plugin --save-dev
```

Then, in your webpack.config.js:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackRootPlugin = require('html-webpack-root-plugin');

const config = {
  ... 
  plugins: [ new HtmlWebpackPlugin(), new HtmlWebpackRootPlugin() ]
  ...
}
```

Now, the generated index.html will have `<div id="root"></div>`in the body.

Answer (score 1):

If someone still struggles on this, you need to specify your relative path to the template:

```
 plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html'
    })
  ]
```

It takes your template from "src/index.html" and builds it in "your_folder/index.html".